# Binding a Datagrid ComboBox MVVM model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a WPF data Combobox binding question.
I have read many pages about this...several days worth so it's time to post a question.

I am working in Visual Studio 2019.  I am using a MVVM model as generated by the entity framework.
I have two SQL tables they look something like this...
[image: SQl tables]

I created a model(Name: EmployeeModel) to manage the backend data.
I also created a model(Name:SourceInspectionView)for the main window (Inspection table).

The `EmployeeModel` has a class for status that looks like this:

```
namespace Sample3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public partial class Status
    {
   [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Status()
        {
            this.SourceInspections = new ObservableCollection<SourceInspection>();
        }

        public int StatusID { get; set; }
        public string Status1 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ObservableCollection<SourceInspection> SourceInspections { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `SourceInspectionView` has a class for the inspections that looks like this:

```
namespace Sample3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public partial class SourceInspectionView
    {
        public Nullable<int> StatusID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My WPF form is called `Mainwindow2`.
The code behind looks like this:

```
 namespace Sample3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
    {
        private SourceInspectionEntities _context = new SourceInspectionEntities();
        private BackEnddata _context2 = new BackEnddata();



        public MainWindow2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ButtonSave(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
            this.SourceManagerGrid.Items.Refresh();

        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource StatusviewSource =
          ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("StatusViewSource")));
            _context2.Status.Load();
            StatusviewSource.Source = _context2.Status.Local;



            System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource MySourceInspectionsViewSource =
            ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("SourceInspectionViewSource")));
            _context.SourceInspectionViews.Load();
            MySourceInspectionsViewSource.Source = _context.SourceInspectionViews.Local;




            this.SourceManagerGrid.Items.Refresh();


        }

        private void ButtonSettings(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow MySettings = new MainWindow();
            MySettings.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

My Xaml looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="SourceManagerGrid" DataContext="{StaticResource SourceInspectionViewSource}"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="top" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding StatusID}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Status"  Header="Status" Width="Auto" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding StatusID}" SelectedValuePath="" >
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" >
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source= {StaticResource StatusViewSource}}"/>
                        <Setter Property= "DisplayMemberPath" Value="Status1" />
                        <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source= {StaticResource StatusViewSource}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="StatusID" />
                        <Setter Property= "DisplayMemberPath" Value="Status1" />
                        <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="CustomerName" Binding="{Binding CustomerName}" Header="CustomerName" Width="auto" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So here is the problem:

1. The data in the main window form should populate and show the current status as words(Started, Finished).
2. When the user clicks the drop down box they should see the list of options from the status table as words(Started, Finished).  However, I need to store the StatusID in the SQl table.  Not the words.

My current code will populate the drop down list and show the words. However, when the combo box loses focus, it turns into blank again.

I have seen all manner of solutions, some with code behind, template columns, and straight XAML.

Can you please look at the code and tell me what I'm missing?
I'm not sure if I have the bindings right which I'm guessing is the problem.

Thanks in advance.
Kerry

Comment: Please post your XAML markup.

Comment: Sorry bout that thought I had it in there

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of looking and some testing with data in the database, I realized that there were some database issues.

I corrected those issues, deleted the extra model, combined the two models into one, then cleaned everything up and this code works now.
My thanks to anyone that took a look at it.

Kerry